# Formatting number in Visual Studio for reports running on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, number-formatting

I need to format a number with spaces as thousand separator and no decimals.
Eg. ‘1234567890123,4321’ to ‘1 234 567 890 123’ on a report running on SQL Server.

Under Placeholder Properties --> Number --> Custom in VS it is possible to format numbers in the report.

The only way I can get it to work is by using the format string ‘### ### ### ### ###.’

Problem is that if the number gets bigger I will not get the space separator and the number will look like: ‘543211 234 567 890 123’

Tried (among others) to make a pattern like ‘# ###.’ but without success.

Any idea what to use as pattern if it should be able to cope with any number?

Cheers
/J

Comment: I am curious as to why you are not marking any answers are correct? If the answers are not sufficient, you are welcome to comment, but note that if they solve your issue it is critical that you mark them as correct else the question remains unsolved for any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Report` menu / `Report Properties...` and select `Code` tab. In the text area put the following code.

```
Public Function MySplit(input as String) As String
  Const charNumber = 3
  Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
  For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
  If i Mod charNumber = 0 Then
    sb.Append(" "c)
  End If
  sb.Append(input(i))
  Next
  Dim newString = sb.ToString()
  Return newString
End Function
```

Now use the function in the tablix:

```
=StrReverse(Code.MySplit(StrReverse(Cstr(FLOOR(Fields!Value.Value)))))
```

Replace `Fields!Value.Value` by the field you want to format.

In a tablix like this

[image]

It will produce something like this:

[image]

Alternatively you can use `Switch` function in the `Format` property to determine the format your field needs based on its length:

```
=Switch(
LEN(Cstr(Floor(Fields!Value.Value)))<4,"###",
LEN(Cstr(Floor(Fields!Value.Value)))<5,"# ###",
LEN(Cstr(Floor(Fields!Value.Value)))<6,"## ###",
...,...
...,...
)
```

It works but could be tedious to add every case.

Let me know if this helps.